Why are there Sunglasses in the Medieval Era on Mushoku Tensei?
Why are there Sunglasses in the Medieval Era on Mushoku Tensei?
Syphiette is wearing Sunglasses

There are no Sunglasses in the Medieval Era, are there?
Doesn't that seem anachronistic?
Like these examples on TV tropes
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnachronismStew

Given that this is a fantasy world with elves, monsters, magic, and such, is there any reason to question the existence of sunglasses?

@F1Krazy - Yes. Do you have a problem with me asking?

I've always just thought it a bit silly to look at fantasy worlds filled with all kinds of magical creatures and abilities, that clearly aren't meant to be realistic, and question the existence of minor details like sunglasses. It feels like the obvious answer is "technology progressed differently in that world to the real one, because magic exists". Or for an out-of-universe reasoning, "the writers prioritised the Rule of Cool over historical accuracy".

Of course, that's not to say that the question is off-topic for this site. It just feels... nitpicky.

My apologies, I wasn't trying to be. I was just curious.

It is exactly such anachronisms as out-of-place sunglasses that make us question the world and so the elves, the monsters, and the magic.

Thanks for asking. I had the exact question.

It's medieval era but from another world, here sunglasses were invented after the medieval era, but glasses were invented in the medieval era, there is no reason why sunglasses couldnt have been invented in the medieval era of another world too, there is nothing so much special about sunglasses for them not being able to be invented in the medieval era

@Fumikage Tokoyami - You're welcome!

Calling/Considering it "sunglasses" doesn't make it out of the place in the Medieval era. After all, glasses are not new in the era as there are windows and people did wear spectacles (monocle). So, just take any skilled craftsman, take glass as raw material, tint it and voila, you have a "sunglass". However, that is not a "sunglass" but a magical item called Sunglasses of the Rescuer. But to be fair, the name is a little bit anachronistic.
More details in this Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/mushokutensei/comments/14r1dx1/where_did_fitz_get_those_modern_looking/
